# Variable exporting between asm files

Tags: variables, assembly, arm

In asm file1 I try to export a variable and use it in another.
I've tried to find how to do that from manuals & tutorials, but no success.

So, how can I share a global variable between asm files?

```
  // File 1
  // Here is saved value of a register (r10) to a variable.
  .section .data
  .global r10_save
  r10_save_addr:   .word  r10_save
  
  .section .text
  ldr r13, =r10_save_addr   // Load address for the global variable to some reg (r13)
  str r13, [r10]            // Save r13 to global variable
```

```
  // File 2
  // Here the intention is to use the variable (that should have r10 value stored).
  .section .data
  
  str_r10:
  .asciz "r10 = 0x"
  strlen_r10 = .-str_r10
  
  
  .section .text
  
  /* Here I want to use the reference of a variable 
     which has got its value in other file.
  */
  mov r0, $1            //
  ldr r1, =str_r10      // address of text string
  ldr r2, =strlen_r10   // number of bytes to write
  mov r7, $4            //
  swi 0
```

Comment: `.global foo` makes the symbol-visibility of `foo` "global", so you can reference it from other files by that name.

Comment: Your files aren't trying to reference the same variable, so IDK what you want to happen. 
 But note that `ldr r2, =strlen_r10` will get the *address* of your `int` variable, not the value.  Also you're including the terminating `0` byte from `.asciz` in your length; if it's an explicit-length string that you only pass to a `write` system call, you probably want to use `.ascii` without a zero terminator.

Comment: Thanks for answers. I know that =str_r10 is reference. String termination wasn't the point in this question. I have been uncertain how to refer to the =r10_save_addr. In file 2 there isn't yet the code how to refer correctly to that as I didn't know how to do that. Comment of file 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `extern`  to get the value of `global`  varibles:

```
// File 2
  // Here the intention is to use the variable (that should have r10 value stored).
  .section .data
  
  str_r10:
  .asciz "r10 = 0x"
  strlen_r10 = .-str_r10
  
  
  .section .text
  
  /* Here I want to use the reference of a variable 
     which has got its value in other file.
  */

  .extern r10_save // or EXTERN DATA(r10_save)
  

  mov r0, $1            //
  ldr r1, =str_r10      // address of text string
  ldr r2, =strlen_r10   // number of bytes to write
  mov r7, $4            //
  swi 0
```

Then you can access `r10_save` in the second file too.

Comment: What assembler is that supposed to be for?  In GAS, there's a `.extern` directive but it's ignored (any symbol that isn't defined in the file is assumed to be external, not an error like in some assemblers).  https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Extern.html.  Without a `.`, just `extern`, that's going to be an error.  But yeah, you just use `r10_save` like you would a symbol defined in the current file, if it's `.globl` in the other file.

Comment: Why my variable is not visible in this case in file2, when there is no .extern keyword? r0_save is .global .word Error: (.text+0x158): undefined reference to `r0_save'

Comment: @RPi3_user: `r0_save` is a typo for `r10_save`.  You never defined `r0_save` anywhere.

Comment: @RPi3_user: Or if you are using the same name in both files, then you need to have `.globl r0_save` in the file that defines the symbol, to make the definition visible in the `.o` outside that file.  In asm, the default like file-scope like C `static int foo`.

Comment: Sorry about the typo in my comment/error output. Question is still valid and unanswered. I copy-pasted error of r0_save (my function tries to save all registers from r0 to r10) with exactly the same mechanism...